# SQL Server Compact won't allow subselect but inner join with groupby not allowed on text datatype

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-ce, inner-join, subquery

I have the following sql syntax that I used in my database query (SQL Server)

```
SELECT Nieuwsbrief.ID
    , Nieuwsbrief.Titel
    , Nieuwsbrief.Brief
    , Nieuwsbrief.NieuwsbriefTypeCode
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 
        FROM NieuwsbriefCommentaar 
        WHERE (Nieuwsbrief.ID = NieuwsbriefCommentaar.NieuwsbriefID 
                AND NieuwsbriefCommentaar.Goedgekeurd = 1)) AS AantalCommentaren 
FROM Nieuwsbrief
```

I'm changing now to sql-server-ce (compact edition) which won't allow me to have subqueries like this. Proposed solution : `inner join`. But as I only need a count of the subtable '`NieuwsbriefCommentaar`', I have to use a '`group by`' clause on my base table attributes to avoid doubles in the result set.

However the '`Nieuwbrief.Brief`' attribute is of datatype '`text`'. Group by clauses are not allowed on '`text`' datatype in `sql-server-ce`. '`Text`' datatype is deprecated, but `sql-server-ce` doesn't support '`nvarchar(max)`' yet...

Any idea how to solve this? Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the solution could be easier. I don't know exactly how is your metadata but I think that this code could fit your requirements by simply using LEFT JOIN.

```
    SELECT Nieuwsbrief.ID 
    , Nieuwsbrief.Titel 
    , Nieuwsbrief.Brief 
    , Nieuwsbrief.NieuwsbriefTypeCode 
    , COUNT(NieuwsbriefCommentaar.NieuwsbriefID) AS AantalCommentaren
FROM Nieuwsbrief  
LEFT JOIN NieuwsbriefCommentaar  ON (Nieuwsbrief.ID = NieuwsbriefCommentaar.NieuwsbriefID)
WHERE NieuwsbriefCommentaar.Goedgekeurd = 1
```

Edited: 2ndOption

```
SELECT N.ID, N.Titel, N.Brief, N.NieuwsbriefTypeCode, G.AantalCommentaren  FROM Nieuwsbrief as N LEFT JOIN (SELECT NieuwsbriefID, COUNT(*) AS AantalCommentaren FROM NieuwsbriefCommentaar GROUP BY NieuwsbriefID) AS G ON (N.ID = G.NieuwsbriefID)
```

Please, let me know if this code works in order to find out another workaround..

regards,

Comment: Hi Josemiguel,
thx for your input. However, if you make a count on the subtable i.c. NieuwsbriefCommentaar.NieuwsbriefID, a grouping is required on the other attributes of the SELECT clause.
Error thrown by the SQLce engine: 'In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can only contain aggregates and grouping expressions [Select clause = Nieuwsbrief, ID]

Adding a GROUP BY clause wouldn't be an issue if sqlserverce would allow this on Nieuwsbrief.Brief, but it doesn't as it is of datatype 'text'.

Regards

Comment: Ok, so try: `
SELECT N.ID, N.Titel, N.Brief, N.NieuwsbriefTypeCode  
FROM Nieuwsbrief as N
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT NieuwsbriefID, COUNT(*) AS AantalCommentaren
FROM NieuwsbriefCommentaar  GROUP BY NieuwsbriefID) AS G
ON (N.ID = G.NieuwsbriefID)`

Comment: This query works fine but does not include the count in the result set... ?

Comment: Ups, sorry I forgot the column just add G.AantalCommentaren  as a column. I'm gonna modify it again.

Comment: That's indeed what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!